# pthread_create using 85MB VIRT instead of 8MB VIRT

Tags: c, memory-management, pthreads, heap-memory, virtual

Ok so I understand VIRT != physical RAM and it's often advised to not worry about it etc.

But I'm perplexed as to why each of my pthread_creates result in a VIRT increase of 85MB instead of the usual 8MB as per my ulimit stack setting of 8192 kbytes.

I suspect it's got something to do with heap, but I'm new to C and am not sure about this aspect.

Snippet of my code is:

```
if (tcount == gset_vars->global_threads_max)
{
    for (j = 0; j< tcount; j++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[j], NULL); // close threads
    }
    tcount=0;
}
pthread_create(&tid[tcount],NULL,HTTP_Multi_Thread,(void *)&args[i]);
tcount++;
```

Code notes:

It's within a for loop with 15 iterations, and the resulting VIRT is 1275MB (ie 15*85)

The inner for loop only runs when the gset_vars->global_threads_max var is set to less than 15 (which doesn't impact the resulting VIRT size anyway).

The function call (HTTP_Multi_Thread) just runs some basic libcurl to download a single file and writes it to disk. The args are just the url and local filename.

Note: For the sake of keeping the code snippet short, it doesn't show that after the main loop I am indeed running pthread_join over all threads (tcount).

**Edit: as suggested by @johnbollinger here is a basic, reproducible example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUMT 8

char *urls[NUMT] = {
    "http://example.com",
    "http://example.com",
    "http://example.com",
    "http://example.com",
    "http://example.com",
    "http://example.com",
    "http://example.com",
    "http://example.com"};

char *filenames[NUMT] = {
    "ex1.txt",
    "ex2.txt",
    "ex3.txt",
    "ex4.txt",
    "ex5.txt",
    "ex6.txt",
    "ex7.txt",
    "ex8.txt"};

struct arg_struct
{
    char url[128];
    char filename[128];
};

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

static void *pull_one_url(void *arguments)
{
    struct arg_struct *myargs = arguments;
    char url[128];
    char filename[128];
    strcpy(url, myargs->url);
    strcpy(filename, myargs->filename);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    CURL *curl;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t tid[NUMT];
    int i;
    struct arg_struct args[NUMT];

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    for (i = 0; i < NUMT; i++)
    {
        strcpy(args[i].filename, filenames[i]);
        strcpy(args[i].url, urls[i]);
        pthread_create(&tid[i],
                       NULL,
                       pull_one_url,
                       (void *)&args[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUMT; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "Thread %d terminated\n", i);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    sleep(60);
}
```

The only purpose of the sleep(60) is to allow some analysis time whilst it is running. The WRITEFUNCTION opt might need to be enabled for Windows users.

Comment: If you want us to consider the possibility that the details of your code are relevant to the issue then we definitely need a [mre] with which the behavior can be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger I've added a basic example to my main post. Interestingly, this example allocates around 135MB VIRT per thread, atleast according to htop on my 64bit raspbian OS.

Comment: I didn't ask for a basic example, I asked for a *minimal* one.  Is that what you've provided?  For example, can you remove any of those calls to libcurl functions without curing the large virtual memory footprint?  Which, if any, are essential to observing the behavior you're asking about?

Comment: What if you move the `curl_easy_init()` and `curl_easy_cleanup()` calls to the main thread, and in between pass a (different) handle to each thread?

Comment: I'm trying to move the curl_easy_init() into the main thread, but probably doing it wrong since it's seg faulting, any suggestions as to how I pass an initialised CURL handle to the pull_one_url function, via the the *arguments (struct)? I've tried adding CURL *curl; to the arg_struct then I init in main (loop) like this args[i].curl = curl_easy_init(); which then gets passed in to the func call as pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, pull_one_url, (void *)&args[i]);

Comment: @JohnBollinger by the way, yes I've tested with bare minimum, empty function, passing NULL, no libcurl etc. it allocates the expected ~8MB (VIRT) per thread, instead of the ludicrous 85-135MB (depending on implementation).

Comment: @Grish Since virtual memory is not a scarce resource, there is absolutely nothing ludicrous about allocating large amounts of it. There are applications that allocate 2GB or more of virtual memory just to make file access a bit simpler. On a 64-bit OS, there is no reason to try to minimize this since it is effectively free.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, but the part I don't like is that I suspect it leads to some swapping, very little swapping, but swapping nonetheless. I'm running a server with 1GB RAM, consuming about 200MB RAM, with a about 650 buff/bache and ~600 available. Yet, it is (currently) using 18MB swap!

Comment: MiB Mem :    981.3 total,    137.7 free,    199.7 used,    643.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1962.0 total,   1943.9 free,     18.1 used.    593.3 avail Mem

Comment: @Grish, the approach you describe to opening a CURL handle in the main thread and handing it off to a new thread looks like what I would do (less the needless cast to `void *`).  The libcurl documentation explicitly says that it is ok to convey a handle from one thread to another, as long as two threads cannot use the same handle at the same time, so I expect that to be OK.  If it is causing problems, then Valgrind might be able to tell you somethign about why.

Comment: @Grish That's pro-active swapping of information that remains in memory anyway. The idea is that *if* you later have memory pressure, you don't have to write things out to swap at that later time (when I/O is precious) and can instead do it now (when you have plenty of I/O capacity to spare). This is normal and good and shouldn't concern you. You should *want* this to happen because it has *zero* cost and could avoid having to write data to swap later. In any event, there's no connection between virtual memory usage and swap usage because only dirty pages get written to swap.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ulimit` stack setting affects only the starting stack for the process. It has no effect whatsoever on the stack size for newly-created threads. For that, you need to use `pthread_attr_setstacksize`.

Comment: I had tried this, and for some reason no matter how small or large I set the stack size to, it has zero impact on the VIRT allocation size reported in htop.

Comment: @Grish Post your code.